# Orbeon compilation error: Package Scala does not have a member Int

Tags: scala, compilation, int, member, orbeon

I am currently trying to build orbeon-forms-master using IntelliJ with scala-sdk-2.11.7 plugin activated. I have one critical error I get stuck on :

```
Error:scalac: Error: package scala does not have a member Int
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: package scala does not have a member Int

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.scala$reflect$internal$Definitions$DefinitionsClass$$fatalMissingSymbol(Definitions.scala:1186)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.getMember(Definitions.scala:1203)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$ValueClassDefinitions$class.valueClassSymbol(Definitions.scala:77)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$ValueClassDefinitions$class.IntClass(Definitions.scala:114)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.IntClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:153)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.IntClass(Definitions.scala:153)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$ValueClassDefinitions$class.IntTpe(Definitions.scala:127)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.IntTpe$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:153)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.IntTpe(Definitions.scala:153)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.sig2type$1(ClassfileParser.scala:627)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.sig2type$1(ClassfileParser.scala:725)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.scala$tools$nsc$symtab$classfile$ClassfileParser$$sigToType(ClassfileParser.scala:771)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getType(ClassfileParser.scala:286)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseMethod(ClassfileParser.scala:565)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.scala$tools$nsc$symtab$classfile$ClassfileParser$$queueLoad$1(ClassfileParser.scala:480)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$parseClass$1.apply$mcV$sp(ClassfileParser.scala:490)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:495)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:136)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:347)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:347)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:347)

at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:347)

at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:211)

at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1489)

at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.initialize(Symbols.scala:1634)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1394)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1215)

at xsbt.CachedCompiler0$$anon$2.<init>(CompilerInterface.scala:105)

at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:105)

at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:94)

at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:22)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:101)

at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:47)

at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:29)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:67)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:24)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)

Warning:scalac: No 'scala-library*.jar' in module dependencies [formBuilder]
Warning:scalac: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
```

I haven't touched a single line of code, and I can definitely not find where this error originates from.

I have also checked other posts regarding this error that can happen when using Play Framework, but they don't seem to fit my needs... Any idea?

Comment: Try using sbt for the build

Comment: Seems to have worked when using sbt with cmd, thanks !